# how can i add reply message in inversejs conversejs

Tags: javascript, converse.js

I use inverse.js with an openfire server and I would like to add the option to reply to messages in group conversations, can you help me?

I tried the code from a friend here on the forum for converse.js but the folders and paths are different

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.